# How would I pass information from one PHP to another?

Tags: php

I need to create a landing page that's dynamic to information picked up by a form that executes a php script.

Person submits form > PHP Code sends me an email > PHP code that displays information

I have a hidden input in every form that identifies what form it is, and depending on what the value or "identification" of the form a specific code on the php is executed using a `switch` and I thought that maybe I could use that same identifier to execute another `switch` on the page after that. My problem is I don't know how to carry that value or identifier from one php to the other.

So just to reiterate, I want to know how to move or copy variables from one php to another, after `mail()` is executed.

Im using $request to get those variables

Comment: How do you execute those PHPs? Do you `require`/`include` them?

Comment: Just to get this straight, you want to send an E-Mail and display the verification, correct? Now allow me to ask...why don't you do both in the same script? Or rather, have the display script use `include` on the PHP script and send the mail from there?

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea about php best practices and I'm unsure whether its good to make a php script so long... its already like 400 lines. And I believe it's safer as well to make a separate landing page.

Comment: so, what exactly is  the question? How to send the user to a "landing page" after the form is submitted, or simply just how to send variables to another PHP-page?

Comment: The second to last line of my question says what I need

Answer (score 0):

Keep this source form identifier and render it into your new form identifier field. It will deliver the response form with same identifier

Answer (score 0):

after you do your `Mail()` thing, call a function that runs whatever you want.

If the classes or functions you want to run are not available you must `include` or `require` them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about what you are asking for, but due the comments I'll make a try to answer it.

When I create forms I usually have one page with the actual form and another page that handles the data. When the data is handled I simply redirect the user back to the form and then give them feedback.

The reasons I'm using two separate pages are the following:

1. I like to keep the code for the form and the handler separated.
2. Users can't accidently submit the form again by refreshing the page.
3. The same handler can be used by eventual Ajax and uphold progressive enhancement.

An extremely simplified example below.

**form.php:**

```
<?php
  //Start session
  session_start();

  //If the session variable has been set
  if($_SESSION['remember'])
  {
    ## DISPLAY FEEDBACK ##
  }
  else
  {
    ## DISPLAY FORM ##
  }

  //Delete the session variable
  unset($_SESSION['remember']);
?>
```

**req.form.php**

```
<?php
  //Start session
  session_start();

  //If a form has been submited
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    ## HANDLE THE DATA ##

    //Set a session variable
    $_SESSION['remember'] = true;

    //Redirect the user back to the form
    header('Location: /form.php');
    exit;
  }
?>
```